# How to populate ViewChildren.nativeElement.children?

Tags: angular, jasmine

I'm using `ViewChildren` to populate my `hiddenCounts` array.

```
  @ViewChildren('myContainers') containers: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  public hiddenCounts: number[] = [];

  private setHiddenCounts() {
    const containerArr = this.containers.toArray();
    const countArr = Array(this.connectors.length).fill(0);

    containerArr.forEach((container, index) => {
      countArr[index] = 0;
      const children = container.nativeElement.children;

      if (children.length) {
        const baseOffset = children[0].offsetTop;
        let baseWidth = children[0].clientWidth + 1; // +1 to round up

        for (let i = 1; i < children.length; i++) {
          if (children[i].offsetTop !== baseOffset) {
            countArr[index]++;
          } else {
            baseWidth += children[i].clientWidth + 4 + 1; // +4 for gap, +1 for rounding up
          }
        }
        container.nativeElement.style.width = `${baseWidth}px`;
      }
    });
    this.hiddenCounts = countArr;
  }
```

I'm trying to write a unit test for this, but can't seem to figure it out. After a bunch of reading, this is what I have so far

```
  it('setHiddenCounts should set hiddenCounts ', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();

    const documentFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('div.myContainers').forEach((node) => {
      documentFragment.appendChild(node);
    });
    const htmlCollection = documentFragment.children;

    const mockContainers = new QueryList<ElementRef>();
    mockContainers.reset([htmlCollection]);
    
    component.containers = mockContainers;

    component.setHiddenCounts();
    expect(component.hiddenCounts).toEqual([.....]);
  });
```

The issue is that my mock containers' `nativeElement` is undefined (as well as the `nativeElement.children`), but when I `console.log(mockContainers)` I can see the children's DOM in `_results`.

Unsure how can I mock this properly.